# Android Studio Error: class, interface, or enum expeted

Tags: java, arrays, android-studio, enums, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to do an insert test data in my database, but is not working.

Follow this video as a reference, but it did not work: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RPi7ueKwEXg

See below:

```
package com.bytemeta.bytenota.dominio;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.*;
import android.database.sqlite.*;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.*;

public class RepositorioCadastro{
    private SQLiteDatabase conn;
    public RepositorioCadastro(SQLiteDatabase conn){
        this.conn = conn;
    }
        public void testeInserirCadastro(){
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put("NOME", "THIAGO");
                conn.insertOrThrow("CADASTRO", null, values);
            }
        }
    }

    public ArrayAdapter<String> buscaCadastro(Context context){

        ArrayAdapter<String> adpCadastro = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        Cursor cursor = conn.query("BYTENOTA_DB",null,null,null,null,null,null,null);

        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

            cursor.moveToFirst();
            do {
                String NOME = cursor.getString(1);
                adpCadastro.add(NOME);
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return adpCadastro;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android Studio throws that error when you have code out of the class declaration.
Your `public ArrayAdapter<String> buscaCadastro` is out of the class right now. Remove the extra closing curly brace after `testeInserirCadastro`, that should fix it.

Comment: Funcionou! Muito obrigado! :D But appear other problems that I checked. Grateful.

Answer (score 1):

I found this with an encoding problem.

copy your source code somewhere and make it is in UTF-8. Then, use the applied code to your project again.

You can also change the encoding format at the bottom of the Android Studio. In this case, you need to change it to UTF-16 and save then again to UTF-8 and save.

[image]