# Error Class, Interface or Enum expected

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I Have been troubleshooting with android studio when I try to build or open the app. I have looked over the code, but can't seen to find the problem. I tried to search for the error but couldn't find it.

Build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.retardoinc.simpeclick"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Error:
[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvvXd.png)

Source code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        Button btnClick;
        Button btnReset;

        TextView txtCount;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            btnClick = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
            btnReset = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

            txtCount =  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.gold);

            btnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String countValue= txtCount.getText().toString();
                    int random = (int )(Math.random() * 25 + 1);
                    int intCountValue = Integer.parseInt(countValue);
                    intCountValue = intCountValue + random;

                    txtCount.setText( String.valueOf(intCountValue));
                }
            });

            btnReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    txtCount.setText( String.valueOf(0));

                }
            });

            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: txtCount in anonymous listener call?

Comment: last line check `};` . remove `;`

Comment: It can be an encoding problem. check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31665663/android-studio-error-class-interface-or-enum-expeted/53350503#53350503

Answer (score 0):

`MainActivity` is your `Activity` which is one java class. You can not end it with `;`.

As well as there is one extra bracket at the end of your code, remove it.

Remove `};` from end of code and **Rebuild** your project, everything else is fine.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     //your rest code
}
```