# issue with duplicating spinner - Android Studio

Tags: android, duplicates, android-spinner

I'm having an issue when I'm trying to duplicate a spinner (when a button is pressed). Following is my create.java code and my MyListAdapter.java code. Am I missing something obvious out in my code? I have been trying to follow a sample of what Mohammad did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51691959/9890386) . Thank you for the help.

**create.java**

```
public class create extends AppCompatActivity {


    Button buttontest;
    private LinearLayout mLinearLayout;

    private ArrayList<Spinner> mSpinners;





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);




        mSpinners = new ArrayList<>();

        mLinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.my_linearLayout);

        mLinearLayout.addView(makeSpinner());    // First spinner

        Button duplicateSpinner = findViewById(R.id.bt_duplicate);
        duplicateSpinner.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Spinner spinner = makeSpinner();
                mLinearLayout.addView(spinner);      // Add another spinner

            }
        });

        Button getSpinner = findViewById(R.id.bt_getSpinner);
        getSpinner.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                for (int i = 0; i < mSpinners.size(); i++) {      // Read all spinners
                    Spinner spinner = mSpinners.get(i);
                    Log.i("TAG", spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private Spinner makeSpinner() {


        //opens csv
        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.shopitems);
        CSVFile csvFile = new CSVFile(inputStream);
        List<String> itemList = csvFile.read();
        MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(this, R.layout.listrow, R.id.txtid, itemList);
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        return spinner;



    }

    private class CSVFile {
        InputStream inputStream;

        public CSVFile(InputStream inputStream){
            this.inputStream = inputStream;
        }

        public List<String> read(){

            List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            try {
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] row = line.split(",");
                    resultList.add(row[1]);
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Main",e.getMessage());
            }
            finally {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("Main",e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            return resultList;
        }
    }}
```

**mylistadapter code**

```
public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    int groupid;
    List<String> items;
    Context context;
    String path;

    public MyListAdapter(Context context, int vg, int id, List<String> items) {
        super(context, vg, id, (List<String>) items);
        this.context = context;
        groupid = vg;
        this.items = items;

    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView textid;
        public TextView textname;

    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        {





            View rowView = convertView;
            if (rowView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                rowView = inflater.inflate(groupid, parent, false);
                ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.textid = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtid);
                viewHolder.textname = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtname);
                rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
            }
            // Fill data in the drop down.
            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
            String row = items.get(position);
            //holder.textid.setText(row[0]); prints aisle number, dont need

            holder.textname.setText(row);


            return rowView;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What issue are you getting

Comment: logcat:  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first. (The app unexpectedly stops)

Comment: Also, the issue seems to be at line 48 on my create.java . I don't see what is wrong though and would like pointers.

Comment: In your makeSpinner() method you are fetching an already existing spinner while in the answer you are following, makeSpinner should create a brand new Spinner not an already existing one in your layout.

Comment: Is it possible to just use the spinner I have already created?

Comment: You can but then it will only be added once, you can’t recreate more than one of the existing. Why not create new ones such as the answer you mentioned?

Comment: I mean that, can I create one that still follows the same values I've done i.e having the spinner getting values from the csv file

Comment: Yes you can. So you want multiple spinners right? Every time you click duplicate you get a new spinner that has values from csv file?

Comment: Yep exactly; hit duplicate and the spinner which is populated with the csv values, is duplicated with the same values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your makeSpinner() method as follows:

```
private Spinner makeSpinner() {
    //opens csv
    InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.shopitems);
    CSVFile csvFile = new CSVFile(inputStream);
    List<String> itemList = csvFile.read();

    //Create new spinner
    Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this, Spinner.MODE_DROPDOWN);

    // Setup layout
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    spinner.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(this, R.layout.listrow, R.id.txtid, itemList);

    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    //Add it to your list of spinners so you can retrieve their data when you click the getSpinner button
    mSpinners.add(spinner);
    return spinner;
}
```

Also this `R.id.spinner` is currently useless.

**Edit: Answer to question in comments: Add button or check box as well**

Create checkbox method:

```
private CheckBox makeCheckbox() {
    //Create new Checkbox
    CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox(this);

    // Setup layout
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    checkbox.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    checkbox.setText("YourCheckboxText"); //TODO Change to what you want
    return checkbox
}
```

Create AppCompatButton method:

```
private AppCompatButton makeButton() {
    //Create new Button
    AppCompatButton button = new AppCompatButton(this);

    // Setup layout
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    button.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    button.setText("YourButtonText"); //TODO Change to what you want
    return button;
}
```

Whenever you want to add a button or a check box add this code:

```
    //Add a new button
    AppCompatButton newButton = makeButton();
    mLinearLayout.addView(newButton);      // Add another button

    //Add a new checkbox
    CheckBox newCheckbox = makeCheckbox();
    mLinearLayout.addView(newCheckbox);      // Add another checkbox
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177549/discussion-on-answer-by-mr-o-issue-with-duplicating-spinner-android-studio).