# Error .java:23: error: class, interface, or enum expected import java.util.*;

Tags: java

I am not sure why I get continuing told the error of java22 in my code.
I searched other person's question like around. like here 
[Compiler error: "class, interface, or enum expected"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749994/compiler-error-class-interface-or-enum-expected)

But I could not find suitable answer for this. 
It seems like error not only class, interface or enum import part. Some cording has issue it.
But but if so I would like to know, which part is course of the problem in this case?

Also, I would like to know the if I want disable to use the num2 for case2. Since it is factorial, it should ask only num1.

Thank you for all the help.

***This is the message***

```
Calc.java:22: error: class, interface, or enum expected
import java.util.*;
^
1 error
```

***This is a code part***

```
import java.util.*;
public class Calc
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    NumCalc calc = new NumCalc();
    System.out.println("Welcome to Math NumCalc!\nPlease choose an option:" 
    + "\n\t1 " + "- add two real numbers" 
    + "\n\t2 " + "- subtract two real numbers"
    + "\n\t3 " + "- multiply two real numbers"
    + "\n\t4 " + "- devide two real numbers"
    + "\n\t5 " + "- get the factorial of an number"
    + "\n\t6 " + "- menu"
    + "\n\t0 " + "- exit"
    );
    calc.run();
}
}

import java.util.*;
public class NumCalc 
{
private int option = -1;
private Scanner scan, num1, num2;
//private int opt;
double ans  = 0.0;
//int category;

public NumCalc()
{
    scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
}

// entry point for class
public void run()
{
    System.out.println("\n? " + scan);
    int scan = scan.nextInt();

    for (int i=0;i < count; i++)
    {
        option = option + scan.nextInt(); 
    }

    System.out.println("Enter 1st num:");
    int num1 = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter 2nd num");
    int num2 = scan.nextInt();

    switch (option)
    {
        case 6:
        ans = num1 + num2;
        System.out.println(num1 + " + " + num2 + "=" + ans);
        break;
        case 5:
        ans = num1 - num2;
        System.out.println(num1 + " - " + num2 + "=" + ans); 
        break;
        case 4:
        ans = num1 * num2;
        System.out.println(num1 + " * " + num2 + "=" + ans);
        break;            
        case 3:
        ans = num1 / num2;
        System.out.println(num1 + " / " + num2 + "=" + ans);
        break;
        case 2:
        num2 = boolean(false); // No 2nd number.
        int ans = 1; 
        for (i = 1;i <= n; i++)
        {
            ans *= n;
        }
        break;
        System.out.println("Factorial of" + num1 + " = ");
        case 1:
        //opt = opt + scan.nextInt();
        continue;
        default:
        close();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: is this all in one single java file?

Comment: You can't have **2** public classes in a *single* .java file. Save class `Calc` in a file called `Calc.java`, and save class `NumCalc` in a different file called `NumCalc.java`.

Comment: @RamanShrivastava It has to be, because the error is complaining about the `import` statement in line **22**.

Comment: @Andreas - Exactly. He needs to have individual java files for each public class.

Comment: For reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336692/java-multiple-class-declarations-in-one-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution, as other people have said, is to split your two `public` classes into two separate `.java` files.  That will solve both the error you've already encountered and another that you were going to encounter later...  but "too many public classes" is *not* what your Java compiler is complaining about.  The real reason you're getting that error is that **you can't put `import` statements after `class` declarations**.

The error message is easy to misread.  It seems to be complaining about *what* you're importing --- probably provoking a response like, "But I *am* importing a class!".  But note where the `^` is pointing --- not at `java.util.*`, but at the word `import`:

```
Calc.java:22: error: class, interface, or enum expected
    import java.util.*;
    ^
1 error
```

This error is actually complaining about the out-of-place `import` statement --- it shouldn't be there at all.  Once you've declared your first `class`, it's too late to `import` anything else.  In a roundabout way, it actually says so:  By line 22 of `Calc.java`, nothing can appear at the top level but type declarations --- the "`interface`, `class`, or `enum`" it mentioned --- so encountering a line that starts with `import` is "unexpected", meaning not allowed.

You can verify this by commenting out the second `import` (line 22) and compiling.  You'll still get errors, but different ones.

As an aside, you *are* allowed to `import java.util.*;` more than once.  The redundant statements will be ignored... as long as they're in the right place.  You can verify this by moving the second `import` up to around line 3 or 4 and compiling.  Again, you'll still get errors, but not about that.

### The Correct Order

A single `.java` file (called a "compilation unit" in the language spec) has the following three parts, which *must* appear in this order:

1. Zero or one `package` declarations.
2. Zero or more `import` statements.
3. Zero or more top-level type declarations, like `class`, `enum`, or `interface`.

From the Java 1.8 Language Specification, [Section 7.3: "Compilation Units"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.3)]:

> `CompilationUnit` is the goal symbol ([§2.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-2.html#jls-2.1)) for the syntactic grammar ([§2.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-2.html#jls-2.3)) of Java programs. It is defined by the following productions:
>
> > `CompilationUnit`:
> >     [[`PackageDeclaration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-PackageDeclaration)] {[`ImportDeclaration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-ImportDeclaration)} {[`TypeDeclaration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-TypeDeclaration)}
>
> A compilation unit consists of three parts, each of which is optional[...]

In case that last phrase made you wonder:  Yes, a completely empty `.java` file *will* compile without warnings... and without producing any `.class` files.

### Solutions

As has been pointed out by others, you can't have more than one top-level `public` class or other type declaration in a single file.  Unless you're willing to nest one of `Calc` and `NumCalc` inside the other, they have to split up into `Calc.java` and `NumCalc.java`.

Actually, you *could* sidestep the problem by reducing one class's visibility to package-default, but that's fragile and not the way Java is generally done.  If you tried to use the package-default class in any other `.java` file, even one in the same package, it would fail to compile because it couldn't find the supposedly-package-visible class --- either `Calc` would be in the wrongly-named `NumCalc.java` (*not* where the compiler will look for it), or `NumCalc` would be hiding out inside `Calc.java`.

But why bother with all that?  You could **combine the two classes into one class** very easily, and have a more coherent project.  (I'm not sure why they're separate classes in the first place.)